# Generate SQL Server Compact 3.5 to SQL script?

Tags: sql-server, code-generation, compact-database

I need to convert a SQL Server Compact database file to SQL Server, so I think generate script is the best way, but I can't find anything in SQL Server CE Toolbox 3.5

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Here is a Microsoft tutorial on the subject http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/migrate-a-database-to-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving data from SQL Compact to SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229572/moving-data-from-sql-compact-to-sql-server-2008)

Comment: In the SQL Server Compact Toolbox you can both script a database or Migrate directly

Comment: Oh thank Erik, I just didn't see it, the third item in context menu: "Script Database", I can't believe meet the author here :)